# What does "train off" mean?

Tags: verbs

Here is the sentence:

And you find that you've been training off very nice high-quality images downloaded off the Internet.

What does "is training off" really mean?
Could you please rephrase the sentence?

Can I interpret this sentence as "you've been working on very nice high-quality images downloaded off the Internet" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"to be training off X" = to experience training which is based on X

*"I failed the exam because I was training off an old textbook"*

Rephrased, and with some sample elements added for context, I would suggest:

> But our operating environment is different from your training. You'll find that while your training had very nice, high-quality images downloaded from the internet, most of the images we generate during real-world conditions are very rudimentary and functional.